# group method for activerecord. Docs are confusing?

Tags: activerecord

I don't get what this means in the Rails tutorial:

group(*args) public
Allows to specify a group attribute:

```
User.group(:name)
```

=> SELECT "users".* FROM "users" GROUP BY name
Returns an array with distinct records based on the group attribute:

```
User.group(:name) [User id: 3, name: "Foo", ...>, #User id: 2, name: "Oscar", ...>]
```

I don't see the grouping with the example they gave...

Comment: I don't understand what your question is or what you are expecting?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Group is most useful (I think) if you are trying to count stuff in your database or if you join multiple tables. Let me give a few examples.

1.
If you want to know how many users there are in your data base with each name then you can do:

```
User.group(:name).count
```

this will return a hash looking something like this:

```
{ ann: 4, bert: 15, cecilia: 3 ... }
```

I do not know why there are so many Berts in your database but anyway...

2.
If your users have related records (for instance cars) the you can use this to get the first car included in your activerecord model (the reason it will be the first is because of how group works and is further explained in the link below)

```
User.joins(:cars).select('users.*, cars.model as car_model, cars.name as car_name').group('users.id')
```

Now all records in this result will have a method called `car_model` and one called `car_name`.

3. You can count how many cars each user has with one single query.

   User.joins(:cars).select('users.*, count(cars.id) as car_count').group('users.id')

Now all records will have a `car_count`.

For further reading: [Mysql group tutorial](http://www.tizag.com/mysqlTutorial/mysqlgroupby.php)

Hope this shed enough light over groups for you to try them out a little bit. I do not think you can fully understand them until you worked with them a little bit.